# java: java.util.Date cannot be cast to java.sql.Date

Tags: java, sql, sql-server

Estoy realizando un proyecto, al momento de querer guardar unos datos me sale error cuando reconoce la fecha, este columna esta en Date.

Estoy utilizando un patrón MVC:

En en Modelo tengo los constructores y en el Controlador tengo los script, siempre indicando que la columna fecha es Date

Este código es el que uso en el botón guardar

```
Clientes_Modelo cliente = new Clientes_Modelo(); 
Guardar_Clientes controlcliente = new Guardar_Clientes();

try {
    if(N_Documento.getText().isEmpty()){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Complete el campo Número de Documento");
    }else{
        if(!controlcliente.ExisteCliente(N_Documento.getText().trim())){
            cliente.setTipoDocumento(T_Documento.getSelectedItem().toString().trim());
            cliente.setNumeroDocumento(N_Documento.getText().trim());
            cliente.setRazSocial(R_Social.getText().trim());
            cliente.setNombres(Nombres.getText().trim());
            cliente.setApellidos(Apellidos.getText().trim());
            cliente.setCelular(Celular.getText().trim());
            cliente.setTelefono(Telefono.getText().trim());
            cliente.setEstado(Estado.getSelectedItem().toString().trim());
            cliente.setCorreo(Correo.getText().trim());
            cliente.setDepartamento(Departamento.getSelectedItem().toString().trim());
            cliente.setProvincia(Provincia.getSelectedItem().toString().trim());
            cliente.setDistrito(Distrito.getSelectedItem().toString().trim());
            cliente.setRepreVentas(Repre_Venta.getSelectedItem().toString().trim());
            cliente.setFechaRegistro(Fecha_Registro.getDate());
            if(controlcliente.Guardar(cliente)){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Registro Almacenado Satisfactoriamente");
                T_Documento.setSelectedIndex(0);
                N_Documento.setText("");
                R_Social.setText("");
                Nombres.setText("");
                Apellidos.setText("");
                Celular.setText("");
                Telefono.setText("");
                Correo.setText("");
                Repre_Venta.setSelectedIndex(0);
                Provincia.setSelectedIndex(0);
                Departamento.setSelectedIndex(0);
                Distrito.setSelectedIndex(0);
                Estado.setSelectedIndex(0);
            }else{
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error al Registrar Datos");
            }
        }else{
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El Cliente ya se encuentra en la Base de Datos");
        }
    }
    
 } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e.toString());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

El sql.Date es una subclase de Date hasta donde tengo entendido, así que sqlDate conoce de la existencia de Date, pero Date no.

En otras palabras, sql.Date se puede convertir en util.Date, pero no al revés.

Posibles soluciones:

1.- Manejar como varchar en la DB los campos de fecha y antes de subirlo manejarlo con SimpleDateFormat para darle un formato que gustes.

2.- Hacer una instancia de util.Date con tus datos a mandar y eso pasarlo en forma de long al sql.Date

```
java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date(); // O la fecha en clase Date que vas a mandar

java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(date.getTime());
```

Lo que hace el .getTime() es que regresa el tiempo pasado en milisegundos.